# I want a shortcut to appear in the VS 2008 toolbar when I install my application

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I want a shortcut to appear automatically in the VS 2008 toolbar when I install my application.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a [Visual Studio Addin](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/AddIns11292005015631AM/AddIns.aspx) that adds a toolbar to the Visual Studio IDE.

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN article might help:

[Displaying Add-ins on Toolbars and Menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165623.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many different ways to do it - you will have to be more specific.

You can register your utility as an external tool - no programming involved. You can do an add-in or a command on any number of context or main menus, etc. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/bb980955.aspx) is a good starting point